# How to refresh watchkit interface controller upon receiving push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, watchkit

My app updates its viewControllers upon receiving push notifications, in the iOS app I used the method `didReceiveRemoteNotification` inside the `appDelegate` to check the remote notification and update the displayed viewController according to the notification type and attached data

Now I need to do the same process to update the main interface controller on the watch extension

anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods:

```
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification; // when the app is launched from a notification. If launched from app icon in notification UI, identifier will be empty
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification; // when the app is launched from a notification. If launched from app icon in notification UI, identifier will be empty
```